# How to make an annotation event system?

Tags: java, events, annotations, system

I'm trying to make an annotation-based event system where like you would register a class implementing an interface and then you can use the events that have an @interface above the methods that are called. Like so:

Wherever.java

```
EventManager.callEvent(new HelloEvent);

EventManager.register(new ClassThatImplementsListeenr);

@EventHandler
public void onHello(HelloEvent event) {
    event.sayHello();
}
```

Ok I understand a lot of this like registering (adds them to arraylist) and making a listener interface plus Event interface. New Events will implement Event, and an @Interface called EventHandler that will only work with methods. THE MAIN part is what I don't get. How to invoke and check for the annotation.

EDIT I JUST MADE THIS, WOULD IT WORK?

```
Public class EventManager {

    private static List<Listener> registered = new ArrayList<Listener>();

    public static void register(Listener listener) {
        if (!registered.contains(listener)) {
            registered.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public static void unregister(Listener listener) {
        if (registered.contains(listener)) {
            registered.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    public static List<Listener> getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    public static void callEvent(final Event event) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                call(event);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private static void call(final Event event) {
        for (Listener listener : registered) {
            Method[] methods = listener.getClass().getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(EventHandler.class)) {
                    try {
                        method.invoke(listener.getClass().newInstance(), event);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for annotations that have been added to a method by

1. Retrieving all the methods that are available on a class:

   ```
   public void registerListeners(T handler){

   Method[] allMethods = handler.getClass().getMethods();



   }
   ```
2. Check all the methods that have your desired annotation (although I would imagine only one method in any given class should be designated with an event listener-type annotation)

   ```
   List<Method> listenerMethods = new ArrayList<Method>();
   for (Method aMethod: allMethods){

     if(aMethod.isAnnotationPresent(EventHandler.class)){
        listenerMethods.add(aMethod);
     }

   }
   ```
3. Given the specific methods that have the annotation, you could call [`Method#invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) on the shortlist of methods to execute the listener.

Comment: how would I invoke though?

Comment: like look up at the code i just edited, the callEvent would I make a thread for it like new Thread() {
callEvent(event)
} .start();

Comment: wow thank you this made it much more cleaner than it used to be.I never understood what invoking does:/

Comment: is the callEvent thread even need though? or can I directly use call?

Comment: I'mm getting a error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@670e068d
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)